# get a sum of grouped recored

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

First of all here it the [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b846/1).

now you can see in fiddle i have two table named `project` and `working` and now i have grouped project which are grouped together with having same name except second table have `_QA` postfix.

Which means i have successfully implemented query which allows me to group that project but now i also need to SUM planned hours for that two project.

If you see in fiddle its coming `1000` but it must be `2500` meaning sum result of both `project` and `project_QA`

Thanks.

Comment: I don't particularly like working, joining or grouping across substrings. Can you refactor your database using proper relationships between entities?

Comment: [Removing `_QA` from the database schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc171/4) it is not giving `2500`.

Comment: You **SHOULD** include the codes in your question as well. Don't rely on external sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My try.... :

```
SELECT p.name,
  (SELECT SUM(p1.planned_hour)
   FROM project p1
   WHERE REPLACE(p1.name,'_QA','') = REPLACE(p.name,'_QA','') ) AS ProjectPlannedHour,
  SUM( ROUND( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( vv.end_date, vv.start_date ) ) / 3600 ,2)) AS TotalHour
FROM project p
INNER JOIN working vv ON vv.project_id = p.id
GROUP BY  REPLACE(p.name,'_QA','')
ORDER BY TotalHour DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

With Join:

```
SELECT p.name,
       p1.planned_hour AS ProjectPlannedHour,
       SUM(ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(vv.end_date, vv.start_date)) / 3600 ,2)) AS TotalHour
FROM project p
INNER JOIN working vv ON vv.project_id = p.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT REPLACE(name,'_QA','') AS `name`,
                   SUM(planned_hour) AS planned_hour
                   FROM project
                   GROUP BY REPLACE(name,'_QA','')) p1 
         ON REPLACE(p1.name,'_QA','') = REPLACE(p.name,'_QA','')
GROUP BY REPLACE(p.name,'_QA','')
ORDER BY TotalHour DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Result:

```
|    NAME | PROJECTPLANNEDHOUR | TOTALHOUR |
|---------|--------------------|-----------|
| project |               2500 |      4.67 |
```

Maybe somebody give better solution, I yet cant figurout more simple query...

Answer (score 0):

Try another solution -

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NAME) name, SUM(planned_hour) planned_hour, SUM(TotalHour) TotalHour FROM (
  SELECT
    p.name,
    p.planned_hour,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, vv.start_date, vv.end_date)) / 3600 TotalHour
  FROM
    project p
  INNER JOIN
    working vv ON vv.project_id = p.id
  GROUP BY
      p.id) t;
```

It is a bit simplified. The result is:

```
project,project_QA  2500    4,6667
```